# socket.io get value that promise returns instead of promise { pending }

Tags: asynchronous, socket.io, promise

in socket.io i am trying to check if a user exist easily enough to where i can just call

```
if(checkUserExist(uid) == 'true'){
    success();
}else{
    failure();
};
```

so i figured out i need to use promises because the function i use to get info from the database is async so i do this

```
function checkUserExist(uid){

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      webUser.findOne({ _id: uid }, function(err, uid) {
        if(uid){
        console.log("USER EXISTS")
        resolve('true')

        }if(!uid){
          console.log("USER NO REAL")
          resolve('false')
        }
      })
});
```

and when i'm trying to use the function like this

```
socket.on('getAgents',function(uid){
  console.log(checkUserExist(uid))
  if(checkUserExist(uid) == 'true'){
    console.log('user does exist getting agents')
    agentList.find({}, function(err, docs) {  
      docs.forEach(function(d) {
          socket.emit('newAgent', d.agentName)
       });
    });
  }else if(checkUserExist(uid) == 'false'){
    console.log('invalid uid ' + uid)
    socket.emit('serverError', 'Invalid UID '+ uid)
  }
})
```

the returned value is `Promise { <pending> }`

i am not sure what to do i thought that it was a simple enough task but obviously i don't yet know how to do it. is there anybody out there that can help me out.

promises is a fairly new concept to me and i still don't fully understand how they work should maybe use a library like promisify?

Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Well for starters you shouldn't be calling it multiple times. It should be `if`...`else`, and it should be `checkUserExist(uid).then(exists => { if (exists) { ... } else { ... } })`. You should also resolve with boolean values `true` and `false`, not strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `checkUserExist()` returns a promise, not a value.  That's how you coded it!

And, since the value is obtained asynchronously, you can't return the value directly anyway.  See the [canonical answer on that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) for more explanation on that topic.

To make your code work properly, you would have to actually use the promise that your function returns:

```
socket.on('getAgents',function(uid){
    console.log(checkUserExist(uid))
    checkUserExist(uid).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            agentList.find({}, function(err, docs) {  
                if (err) {
                    // decide what to do if there's a DB error here
                    return;
                }
                docs.forEach(function(d) {
                    socket.emit('newAgent', d.agentName)
                });
            });
        } else {
            socket.emit('serverError', 'Invalid UID ' + uid)
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        socket.emit('serverError', 'Error processing UID ' + uid);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help once again so when you use `checkUserExist(uid).then(result =>{})` so if there is a result why does that mean that it is true because couldnt the result be false ?

Comment: @NicholasHendricks - The resolved value in `result` could be either `true` or `false`.  That's why my suggested code does `if (result) {...} else {...}` to check that and process it differently.